# Having inner JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

Is it possible to have inner `JPanel`s?  If it is possible, is it convenient?

I have a `JPanel`

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{

}
```

Inside `MyPanel`, can I put another `JPanel`?

Comment: Do you mean inner class?  If so, yes you can.

Comment: Nested `JPanel`s you mean to say. `JPanel` containing another `JPanel` inside itself :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use:

```
MyPanel myJPanel = new MyPanel();
jPanel.add(myJPanel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put as many panels inside another panel as you want.
But make sure to use the correct LayoutManager for your needs.

Read this tutorial to learn more:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel myJPanel1 = new JPanel();// creating first JPanel
JPanel myJPanel2 = new JPanel();// creating second JPanel

myJPanel1.add(myJPanel2); //adding first panel to second one
```